# Endpoints and AppEngine 1.7.6

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android app connecting to Google Cloud Endpoints. This all works fine if I build the client libraries with an AppEngine 1.7.5 project. However, if I upgrade to AppEngine 1.7.6 the Android client fails to connect to the endpoints with the following error:-

Hostname "1.myappid.appsot.com" cannot be verified.

Has anyone seen the same issue?

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in 1.7.6, it's fixed in 1.7.7